# A large table or a large number of small table?

Tags: mysql

I would like to create an efficient database :

I have 100 000 clients in a table; For each client I have information that will be of at least 1000 rows.
Should I build a table with 100 000 * 1000 rows = 100 000 000 rows ?
or should I create 100 000 tables containing 1000 rows each ?

I need to be able to access the 1000 rows for a client in the quickest way.
What is the fastest way ?

thanks ?

Comment: Single table with `100 000 000 rows` and with proper index for most select queries would be the best option instead of `100 000 tables`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty's probably right, but actually the correct answer is a a database design normalized to (at least) 3NF. This may or may not be the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have so many columns (even lengthy text columns) related with client which will not be required each time and each client other 1000 rows contains light data for example mostly numeric values then you can create 2 tables.

1. client details. (100000 rows)
2. Client transaction (with 100000*1000 rows) but here data size should be less.

Further if you share your sample data then community can help you better. As there can be multiple options and one will work best in one situation and another one in another situation.

Comment: Who's talking about columns?

Comment: thks. My concern is really on the time to retreive the information in the second table and if it is faster to create 100 000 tables. the table effectivly contains numerics

Comment: if client_id in your 2nd table is indexed and it is int type then you can get desired rows quickly even 100000*1000 rows table.